# How can I filter non-sequential identifiers from data organized in a hierarchy in R?

Tags: r, hierarchy

I'm extracting the section names and references within that section from a large document using R.

My results currently look like:

```
    df<-data.frame("sectname"=c("1","1.1","1.2","1.1.1","1.2","3","2","2.1"), "ref"=c("FALSE","2.1", "3", "FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE", "FALSE"))
```

However, the sectnames that are non-sequential in the hierarchy [3,6] are actually refs belonging to the line above.

Is there a functional way to capture these and paste into ref[i-1]?

Desired Output:

```
<sectname> <ref>
1          FALSE
1.1        c("2.1","1.2","3")
1.1.1      FALSE
1.2        3
2          FALSE
2.1        FALSE
```

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. It would be helpful if you provided the desired output so we could test possible solutions to verify they produce the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to iteratively remove the elements of `sectname` that ruin its sequential ordering and paste them onto the elements of `ref` that are not FALSE.

This is possible to do with a `while` loop. The only problem is that `ref` ends up longer than `sectname` since you are making `sectname` shorter but preserving the length of `ref`. They cannot therefore remain as data frame columns.

I suspect from the data structure that these don't naturally belong in rows anyway. Here is how to make the transformation. I will need to leave the result as vectors as it is not clear what kind of data structure they should belong to.

```r
extras <- character()
sectname <- df$sectname
ref <- df$ref

while(TRUE)
{
  vals <- which(diff(order(sectname)) != 1)
  if(length(vals) == 0) break
  i <- vals[1] + 1
  extras <- c(extras, sectname[i])
  sectname <- sectname[-i]
}

ref[which(ref != "FALSE")] <- paste(ref[which(ref != "FALSE")], extras)

ref 
#> [1] "FALSE"   "2.1 1.2" "3 3"     "FALSE"   "FALSE"   "FALSE"   "FALSE"  
#> [8] "FALSE"
sectname
#> [1] "1"     "1.1"   "1.1.1" "1.2"   "2"     "2.1"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>